# need to return relation with api resource

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

i have Children Relation i need it to return with the respond it will be empty i lnow but i need it

```
public function store(Category $category, Path $path,$level,Task $task,Request $request)
{
    \Auth::loginUsingId(1);

    $this->validate($request ,[
        'body' =>'required|max:5000',
    ]);

    $comment = $task->comments()->make([
        'body' => $request->body
    ]);

    $request->user()->comments()->save($comment);

    return new CommentResource($comment);
}
```

Comment: can u share logic u have written in CommentResource class? You need to use "with" keyword to get relations into responce.

Comment: You need to specify the model and the relations you need to return first, as it stands now, it is unclear what you're trying to return